# sessions not working when trying to do admin login

Tags: php

Creating an admin and normal user login, but getting error when running code. Admin log in and directed to index.php and when guest logs in directed too display.php but when log in nothing happpens. Anyoneable to help?
Here is my code for authen_login.php:

```
 <?php  
session_start();
 require('config2.php');

if (isset($_POST['user_id']) and isset($_POST['user_pass'])){

// Assigning POST values to variables.
$username = $_POST['user_id'];
$password = $_POST['user_pass'];



// CHECK FOR THE RECORD FROM TABLE
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_login` WHERE username='$username' and Password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$_SESSION['user_type'] = $count['user_type'];



 if($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin'){ //check if user or password is correct from query


  header("Location: index.php"); //if normal user redirect to app.php

 }
 elseif ($_SESSION['type']) == 'guest'){

 header("Location: display.php"); //if admin user redirect to admin.php

  }
}


 ?>
```

Comment: Have you debug your code? Check what's coming in $_SESSION['type'] before if($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin'){ by putting die;

Comment: Which error do you see when executing the code?

Comment: when run error log this error comes up : PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL.

Comment: then error 500 webpage not displayed comes up after i log in

Comment: your code is open for sql injection. validate and filter the $_POST['user_id'] and $_POST['user_pass']

Answer (score 0):

you have missed a bracket

```
elseif (($_SESSION['type']) == 'guest') // add '(' before $_SESSION['type']
```

Comment: oh yes thanks for spotting that! but now still does not log in comes up with blank screen

Comment: debug it use  die($_SESSION['type']); and check what is value inside $_SESSION['type'].

Comment: when debugging now comes up with a  Undefined index:

Comment: That means you have not created $_SESSION['type'] till. from your sql query assign the user type $_SESSION['type']=$result->user_type

Comment: how do i add this in?

Comment: you need to learn more PHP.  learn from any resource. i cant help you for all code